# Remote desktop with no copy & paste (“read-only”)

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, vnc

Are there any VNC or Remote Desktop clients (like Chrome’s) that let me disable copy & paste or downloading of files to the client computer?

I’d like to give a user access to my computer in “read-only” mode. (I realize I could never stop taking a screenshot, or someone remembering things. My goal is to make theft difficult, not impossible.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable clipboard redirection for remote desktop using GPO. This prevents copy / paste between remote desktop clients and the server for applications like `mstsc.exe` (Remote Desktop).

- **Group Policy Object:**

  - Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host.

    - Do not allow Clipboard redirection = Enabled
- **Registry (DWORD):**

  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services`

    - fDisableClip = 1
- [Do not allow Clipboard redirection](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.TerminalServer::TS_CLIENT_CLIPBOARD)

Comment: Disabling clipboard redirection for remote desktop gives the desired result of not allowing copy / paste while still allowing remote desktop access.

Comment: I'm not sure why you feel like you need to be so combative with your comments, if I'm incorrect that's fine but the original question is asking how to prevent copy and paste between server and remote desktop session, my answer is valid. If you have a better solution, you could respond with an answer or link to previously answered question?

Comment: I didn't mean to be combative.  I apologize.  You are right.. I focused on the VNC part of the question.